# c# Foreach return the same value after iterate Db table

Tags: c#, foreach

i have odd problem . i ma trying to iterate bd Table with 5 row and return this table value + an image as string , well when i check foreach loop all item passed and add to object list  but when it's time to return all value i found 5 same value in list item !!! all belong to last table row ?

```
public class TransferItem
    {
        public  string foodType { set; get; }
        public  string foodName { set; get; }
        public  int foodPrice { set; get; }
        public  string foodDescription { set; get; }
        public byte[] foodImage { set; get; }
       
    }
 

var Transfer = new transferToFront();

                  var mylist = new List<object>();
                        foreach (var obj in FoodObjt)
                  {
                       String filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Images/");
                       Transfer.Id = obj.Id;
                       Transfer.foodName  = obj.foodName;
                       Transfer.foodImage = obj.foodImage;
                       Transfer.foodPrice = obj.foodPrice;
                       Transfer.foodType  = obj.foodType;
                       Transfer.foodDescription = obj.foodDescription;
                       var imageString = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + obj.foodImage);
                       Transfer.Image  = imageString;

                       mylist.Add(Transfer);
                  }
                      

                    return Ok(mylist);
```

[result of iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MvHh.png)

Comment: Where is `FoodObjt` declared

Comment: You have 1 major problem right of the bat, your `transferToFront` class is created once outside the loop and added again many times without creating a new instance. You will have the same object many times in that collection with the value of the last item of your `FoodObjt` collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Transfer` is shared across iterations of the loop, and thus each time you append the **same object** to the list. The memory map looks like:

```
+--------------------------+
|          Transfer        |
+--+----+----+----+---+----+
   |    |    |    |   |
+--+----+----+----+---+--+
|  0    1     2   3   4  |
|         myList         |
+------------------------+
```

So when you change `Transfer`, you change all of the items in the list - *because the're same*.

The solution is to create a fresh new instance for each iteration:

```cs
var mylist = new List<object>();
foreach (var obj in FoodObjt)
{
    var Transfer = new transferToFront();

    String filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Images/");
    Transfer.Id = obj.Id;
    Transfer.foodName  = obj.foodName;
    Transfer.foodImage = obj.foodImage;
    Transfer.foodPrice = obj.foodPrice;
    Transfer.foodType  = obj.foodType;
    Transfer.foodDescription = obj.foodDescription;
    var imageString = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + obj.foodImage);
    Transfer.Image  = imageString;

    mylist.Add(Transfer);
}

return Ok(mylist);
```

Now the memory map looks like:

```
+----------+ +----------+ +----------+ +----------+ +----------+
|Transfer 1| |Transfer 2| |Transfer 3| |Transfer 4| |Transfer 5|
+--+-------+ +-----+----+ +---+------+ +----+-----+ +---+------+
   |               |          |             |           |
   |    +----------+          |             |           |
   |    |    +----------------+             |           |
   |    |    |    +-------------------------+           |
   |    |    |    |   +---------------------------------+
   |    |    |    |   |
+--+----+----+----+---+--+
|  0    1     2   3   4  |
|        myList          |
+------------------------+
```